# JPA Change Event on Entity Graph [EclipseLink]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can I *by only using JPA* somehow keep track of a whole Entity-Graphs state?

Consider having a Hierarchy with two or three classes in them with at least one Collection.

By using JPA @Post... Annotations I can only keep track of the actual entity and not its children and or Collections as it is pretty much just the Data-Base Event wrapped.

I know Hibernate can do that, but I don't want to rely on the implementation of the JPA for doing this.

I would be pretty happy if there was a way to do this with EclipseLink at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're searching for, 
but you can detect change on your entities like so:

```
 Account a = em.merge(account);
 final JpaEntityManager jpaEntityManager = (JpaEntityManager) em.getDelegate();
 final UnitOfWorkChangeSet changeSet = jpaEntityManager.getUnitOfWork().getCurrentChanges();
 final ObjectChangeSet accountChangeSet = changeSet.getObjectChangeSetForClone(a);
 final ObjectChangeSet userChangeSet = changeSet.getObjectChangeSetForClone(a.getUser());
 em.clear();
 //checks only for these 2 specific fields; changeSet.hasChanges() would check for all changes
 return accountChangeSet.hasChangeFor("credits") || userChangeSet.hasChangeFor("name");
```

Hope this somewhat helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but no. I already figured out a way to do this in EclipseLink as EclipseLink handles the @PostUpdate/... etc. methods really well (updates for Collections are sent to the owning entity and so on), which other JPAs sadly don't. I think I will have to stick with a custom implementation for every provider I want to support in my API.

Comment: https://github.com/Hotware/Hibernate-Search-JPA/blob/master/hibernate-search-jpa/src/main/java/com/github/hotware/hsearch/jpa/event/HSearchJPAEventListener.java

Comment: accepted this since I asked a way to do this in EclipseLink would suffice. It kinda doesn't, but I am a man of my word.

Comment: Sad to hear you have to do a custom implementation now. If only Hibernate can do what you require at the moment maybe it would make sense to request this as a feature of an upcoming JPA release?

Comment: EclipseLink has an implementation that works, too. Imo every JPA provider has to have some (at least internal) eventing system that could be leveraged through a general JPA API, but for that there must be a general consensus how the events are distributed. I am currently working on a Hibernate-Search adaption for general JPA (which I need the events for) and I am in contact with some of the hibernate-devs. And yes, this would definitely make sense as a new feature of an upcoming JPA release. In fact, I think I will request this at some point in the future when my stuff is more mature.

Comment: and when I know what I need exactly and how I think it would be best to handle this.

Comment: to rephrase it: the problem is not that JPA providers don't generally have event systems (most I have seen, have it), but that they all have their own custom interfaces :(